# Phrase for a feeling of relief upon finding a solution to a long term irritant

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that would explain the feeling of relief that one sometimes feels when removing a minor irritation, whether physical or mental. For example, settling into a nice bubble bath to wash off a day's dust and sore muscles.

I imagine the phrase I'm searching for would be similar to 'take a weight off my mind' but that one has connotations of being stressed or worried, rather than just annoyed.

I've thought of 'like removing a bur from under the saddle' or 'like pulling a splinter' but I'm having trouble phrasing it as 'I felt like ___ when I (learned how to do something easier/bought a convenience item/took a break for self care/etc).

Is there a common phrase or word to fit this idea? Or is there a way to phase it that would immediately make sense to the audience?